# Ubuntu & Silverlight

Tags: moonlight

I have a business that runs 11 computers that only require 2 bits of extra (i.e. other that the os) software to work - a browser and MS  Silverlight I am currently running on XP but time is running out on that, windows 7 is supported to 2020 and therefore I face a bill of over £1200 to upgrade. 
Is there anyone out there that can provide me with a disc image of Ubuntu and Silverlight already installed and working OR if it is not possible please let me know and if possible how much?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible thanks to Erich Hoover and his pipelight team. You can make yourself Ubuntu ISO after installing silverlight. You can use Ubuntu-Builder to make yourself USB runnable ISO images.

Pipelight can run flash, shockwave, silverlight and unity player through wine [FDS-Team | Pipelight - Installation](http://fds-team.de/cms/pipelight-installation.html)

Comment: ATM I'd suggest using Ubuntu 14.04. I had problems installing Pipelight on 15.10, but on 14.04 it just works (test with Firefox).